# grails when does ID get assigned?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm doing myDomainObject.save(flush: true) and then attempting to read the id assigned to myDomainObject in the next statement, and I get a value of "null".

My application needs to use this id as an invoice # (to send out via a service) as soon as I can get the new id.

My question is, what do I need to do to get the assigned ID value as easily/efficiently as possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there as soon as the save completes.  In fact in unit and integration tests its a good idea to assert that the id is not null as a simple test that the persistence operation was successful.   Are you sure the save is successful?

Check out http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

for how to determine errors.  Specifically the part with

```
if( !b.save() ) {
   b.errors.each {
        println it
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - am checking -- and looking for mechanism / closure to print out all the errors on a domain class (outside a gsp) :-)

Comment: I see :-).  Where are those? :-)  (I'm developing using Intellij, but apparently the Intelligent part hasn't warn off on me yet! ) :-)

Comment: wherever you run grails run-app from.  My answer now has links to documentation that shows you how to print the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't think I had any constraints that would fail, but I did add a dateUpdated and dateCreated field, which is failing:  Field error in object 'b' on field 'dateUpdated': rejected value [null];  Hmm.

Comment: Yup, thanks much for your help, it should have been lastUpdated